# Is there a way to revert to an older Java version on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, java

The Apple website basically says: "install the OS over again".  I'm hoping there is something I can do other than that.

I'm testing a Java app that has known problems with JRE 1.6.0_18 and above.  Somewhere along the line I accepted an OS update that installed JRE 1.6.0_20.  I really want to drop back to 1.6.0_17 which was working well in this environment a few months ago.

I'm running an up-to-date Snow Leopard (10.6.4).

Answer (score 1):

See if this article helps:

[Reinstall Java on Leopard](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2009051215025819)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinstall the OS, try installing OSX in a VirtualBox VM.  The newest versions of VB support OSX guest on OSX host VMs, so you should be able to do it without having to modify your entire system.

If you're just testing the app for a larger purchasing decision, try to get in touch with the developer and explain that an updated build with support for newer VMs is a requirement.

Comment: Mac OS X Server only.